# merge css and js in magento breaks website

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, merge

I want to speed up my magento website. I installed Fooman Speedster, But it was not worked properly. I have uninstalled it.

I want to achieve speed by using the default merge feature in magento. I have enabled the js merge, But website is not loading any type of js files.

I searched for the solution in google, i found that errors should be removed from the js files.

I am getting the errors like "`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined`". Still i am struggling to figure out the errors but i can't. Please some one give instructions to remove this type of errors.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `Unexpected token <` is probably coming from 404 error (ie. The resources is expecting a js file but is receiving a 404 page). Check all the file paths in your JS files. `get` is probably undefined because it is defined in the missing file that is generating the 404

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I solved most of the errors and "add to cart" button is not working after merging. I googled it, many developers asked the same question but i dint find any relevant answer. Please give any hint to sort it out. Thanks again...